# Memcached and Sharding

Tags: java, memcached, sharding

I'm new to both memcached & sharding.

I gone though some articles on both. I need to implement both in my application.

Articles I'd gone through were good but none of them gave me how to use these technologies.

Anyone who can suggest me the links from which I can actually configure them and run the samples.

I want to implement memcached first, then sharding and then both of them together.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm really sorry....
i didn't know about it..

Comment: I updated and you people are amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your memcached client will do all of the sharding for you.  The harder part is knowing what you should cache so it will actually be beneficial to your application.

In general, you *don't* want to cache things like database queries.  You *do* want to cache things that you build from database queries that represent higher-level objects in your application.

Having a good API for storage and retrieval of your applications is a good start.  You might find the [story of memcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/TutorialCachingStory) a good introduction.

Comment: As a useful comment, consider netspy memcache client for java, as it is superfast and already contains sharding support :)

Answer (score 0):

You can below link, hope it will help to get started....

http://sacharya.com/using-memcached-with-java/

http://www.javascool.com/2010/08/31/using-memcached-with-java-applications/